# How do I check if a user has a role in nextcord?

Tags: python, discord, nextcord

I am using nextcord and I am trying to check if a user has a role when they run a command. I have no idea how to do this so I cannot provide an MRE. I imagine that the code will be something like this:

```py
@client.slash_command(name="test")
async def test(interaction:nextcord.Interaction):
 if interaction.user.has_role("Cool"):
  await interaction.send("You are cool!")
 else:
  await interaction.send("You are not cool.")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, It is sort of like this answer but backwards:

```py
@client.slash_command(name="check_role", description="Check if a user has a role", guild_ids=GUILD_IDS)
async def check_role(interaction:nextcord.Interaction, user:nextcord.Member):
  if nextcord.utils.get(interaction.guild.roles, name="Role Name") in user.roles:
    await interaction.send("True!")
  else:
    await interaction.send("False.")
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you will need to get the role first, and then check if a specific member is in that role. Here is an example, however I believe this is not the only way to do this:

```
from nextcord.utils import get

role = get(ctx.guild.roles, name='search for role by name')

if interaction.user in role:
     do something
else:
     do a different thing
```

Hope this helps